# Transcluding a component several times in Angular?

Tags: angular, transclusion

I would like to achieve the following:

```
<s-panel-edicion>
  <s-barra-lateral posicion="right" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true">cualquier contenido</s-barra-lateral>
  <s-barra-lateral posicion="left" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true">cualquier contenido </s-barra-lateral>
 </s-panel-edicion>
```

Right and left are the position of the sidebar and this is my editing component:

```
<div class="container-plantilla">
  <div class="plantilla-template" [ngStyle]="moverBarraLeft">
    <ng-content select="s-barra-lateral"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="plantilla-contenido" [ngClass]="{'plantilla-contenido-oculto':!displayLeft,'plantilla-contenido-no-oculto':displayLeft,'plantilla-contenido-full':displayLeft}">
    <ng-content select="s-contenido"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="plantilla-template" [ngStyle]="moverBarraRight">
    <ng-content select="s-barra-lateral"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only one side is shown. Can someone guide me how I can achieve that? I will appreciate your help.

(My english is not good, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, you need to use 'select' in the following way: 
 `select="[name]"`, then you can use 'name' in any tag.

Your html would look like this:

```
<s-panel-edicion>
  <s-barra-lateral content1 posicion="right" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true"> cualquier contenido</s-barra-lateral>
  <s-barra-lateral content3 posicion="left" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true">cualquier contenido </s-barra-lateral>
</s-panel-edicion>
```

s-panel-edicion:

```
<div class="container-plantilla">
  <div class="plantilla-template" [ngStyle]="moverBarraLeft">
    <ng-content select="[content1]"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="plantilla-contenido" [ngClass]="{'plantilla-contenido-oculto':!displayLeft,'plantilla-contenido-no-oculto':displayLeft,'plantilla-contenido-full':displayLeft}">
    <ng-content select="[content2]"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div class="plantilla-template" [ngStyle]="moverBarraRight">
     <ng-content select="[content3]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Loop Example**

```
<s-panel-edicion>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <s-barra-lateral *ngIf="item.posicion == 'right'" content1 posicion="right" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true"> cualquier contenido</s-barra-lateral>
    <s-barra-lateral *ngIf="item.posicion == 'left'" content3 posicion="left" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true"> cualquier contenido</s-barra-lateral>
  </div>   
</s-panel-edicion>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid that use, I'm looking for a solution where I can add more <s-barra-lateral> and be able to manage it with a for in the ng-content so that it is dynamic according to the position some idea?

Comment: Can you show how you would like it to work? Can you show your code with the ngFor and how you expect it to show?

Comment: I have no idea but I saw something like this I do not know how to apply it
         <div * ngFor = "let item of items">
                 <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet] = "template"> </ ng-container>
         </ div>

Comment: What about the loop example I have added to the answer? Is what you are asking for?

Comment: no, i am need for example PRIMENG      <p-dataTable [value]="cars" [loading]="loading">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable> 
even so vote for your answer but if I achieved something more advanced it would be great

Comment: Okay, thanks and good luck. But, sorry I do not think I still fully understand based on your example.